# Make three menus with three category levels

Tags: categories, menus

I want to have 3 menus of categories, and each menu with diferent level of categories.

First menu with First level categories:

- category 1
- category 2
- category 3

If I go to the first category, I want to show a second menu under de first one with child categories of current category:

- subcategory 1.1
- subcategory 1.2
- subcategory 1.3

And finally, if I go to subcategory 1.1, I want to show a new menu with child categories of current subcategory:

- subsubcategory 1.1.1
- subsubcategory 1.1.2
- subsubcategory 1.1.3

Answer (score 0):

[`wp_list_categories();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) will by default give you a hierarchically nested list of all your categories. Hiding and showing that list, or parts of it, is just a matter of CSS. That sounds like what you need. For example

```
echo '<ul class="my-cats-list">',wp_list_categories(),'</ul>';

// style rules; put in your theme's style.css
.cat-item {
  padding-left:5px;
}
.children {
  display:none;
}
.cat-item:hover>.children {
  display:block;
}
```

That is very minimal but does work.

Comment: Hi!But I want separate menus not in the same list.

Comment: I don't know what that means. Are you talking about clicking a menu and then going to another page for the second menu?

Comment: For example, when I click in a category of the first menu, I will show the first menu and the second menu with his child categories

Comment: That is almost what I did. Replace the `>` in the last rule with a space and that is what you should have. But I suspect that you are still not being clear about what you want. Please edit the question with much more detail.

Comment: I want separate menus in diferente divs